# Image swapping in Javascript, how to reset src?

Tags: javascript

Hello  i want to change image when user mousovers on image and after he mousleavs reset image src, but it doesn't work
this is my html code:

```
<img id="myImage" onmouseover="changeImage()" onmouseleave="resetImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
```

and JS:

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage').image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";     
}

function resetImage() {
     var image = document.getElementById('myImage').image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You are mixing things up..

Use `document.getElementById('myImage').src = "pic_bulbon.gif";`

`____^^--------DOM Element-----------^^_Property_^^--Value--^^`

Try this:

```js
function changeImage() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
}

function resetImage() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
}
```

```css
[src="pic_bulbon.gif"] {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
[src="pic_bulboff.gif"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" onmouseover="changeImage()" onmouseleave="resetImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
```